# SQL to print a value based on the number of rows for a particular value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have three tables as below:

```
--------------------------
Account Number | AGR ID
--------------------------
111               1234
222               2234
---------------------------

 --------------------------
AGR Number | Meter ID
--------------------------
1234              123
2234              223
---------------------------
---------------------------
Meter ID | Meter Read Date
---------------------------
123        2016-01-17
123        2016-03-13
223        2016-11-23
```

---

Now i need to print account Id and a value based on the number of meter reads available in the third table.

For the above data I need an output like:

```
----------------------------------
Account ID  |  Is multiple reads
----------------------------------
111            Y
222            N
```

---

Comment: No it can be one to many as well.

Comment: Table one has one to many relationship with table two. Table two has a many to one relationship with table three.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`GROUP BY` and `CASE` should be enough

```
select
    t1.Account_Number,
    case when count(*) > 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end Is_multiple
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.meter_id = t2.meter_id
group by t1.Account_Number;
```

#### EDIT:

As per the modified schema, this should work:

```
select
    t1.Account_Number,
    case when count(*) > 1 then 'Y' else 'N' end Is_multiple
from table1 t1
inner join table2 t2
on t1.agr_id = t2.agr_id
inner join table3 t3
on t2.meter_id = t3.meter_id
group by t1.Account_Number;
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response GurV. I have another question. What if I have to do multiple joins. For instance table1.acct_id = table2.acct_id and table2.agr_id = table3.agr_id and table3.meter_id  = table4.meter_id and then check the number of values in table 4.

Comment: Can you give me an example please?